# In Symfony 3 app deployed to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, why does database work in dev environment but not in prod?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm a newbie when it comes to AWS, and I'm trying to deploy an application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk for the first time. I've set up a database in the EB console for my environment, and updated the parameters.yml file to include the correct credentials. My application is using Symfony 3.

When I access a page that does not interact with the database, it works just fine in both dev and prod environment. Once I open a page that attempts to open a connection to database in prod, I get a 500 error. However, if I go to app_dev.php first, then open the same page, it reads from the database just fine. When I check the log files, I'm getting a "connected refused" error from attempting to open the page in prod.

Why does dev environment connect to database, but prod doesn't? Is there another configuration I'm forgetting to update?

Comment: Do you use apache? tried to set _AllowOverride_ : All in your config ? i got the same problems can't work in my prod environment, this should fix it :)

Comment: That looks like your app.php doesn't use the right config file. Do you have separate config files for dev and prod environment?

Comment: @Violence are you referring to to .htaccess file or the config.yml file?

Comment: @totas yes, it's a close to vanilla installation of Symfony 3, in that I haven't touched the config files much. There is still a separate config_prod.yml and config_dev.yml

Comment: @Hexel C i mean your webserver config, for example nginx or apache2. You have a config file for your site, there you need to add:         `<Directory /your/project/route>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>`